# How to set/check for a unique value in a column with CHAR (1) = y/n

Tags: mysql, sql, row

I'm not very strong in SQL statements but I would like to know about a thing I'm willing to know.

Imagine a "visible" column that holds 'y' or 'n' values. Is it possible to have **only** a single 'y' without launching a pre-query that updates this table to 'n' value for all rows before setting the desired row to 'y'?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're after.  Do you mean that only a single row in the table can have `Y` at any one time?  This could be done with an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger.

Comment: Add a column constraint, or -even better- make it a domain.

Comment: `AFTER UPDATE` ..interesting. I've never encountered (even thought to) this statement. Thanks @Michael . Anyway, yes. I would like that, for example, in a "Banner" table there were only a single "visible = 'y'" column (so only one visible banner at a time) and the other rows must be with "visible = 'n'".

Comment: @wartoverflow an after update trigger is more complicated than just running two queries as suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to set row with ID 123 to be visible, you can do the following. The first query will not update *all* rows, only the row(s) that are already set to Y:

```
update MyTable set Visible = 'N' where
Visible = 'Y';
update MyTable set Visible = 'Y' where
ID = 123;
```

Another approach is, rather than making Visible a flag, make it a VisibleDate column. Then set that column to the current date for the row you want to be visible. Then, to determine which row is currently visible, select the max date from the VisibleDate column to find the row.

Comment: Yes @RedFilter . That's what I'm actually doing. I thought there was (and it seems it is) an other approach to do so.

Comment: And, what if I delete the "visible" column (so I will not have many 'n' values) and I create a single table with id_banner and visible='y' only that will have only one id_banner ? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider another approach for what you are doing.  Imagine that your table has a primary key (it should) called id.

Create a table called Visible:

```
create table Visible (id int)
```

Now, you can create the flag by the following query:

```
select t.*, (case when v.id is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end) as VisibleFlag
from table t left outer join
     Visible v
     on t.id = v.id
```

You can wrap this query in a view, to simplify other coding.

This gives you the ability to set one row to visible, without affecting other rows.  The performance should be quite good, since looking up one row in a table, using the primary key is a fast operation.  You can also use a similar table for other types of flags, but you have to specify the name of the flag in each row.

Comment: Yes @Gordon Linoff this is what I thought minutes ago. Delete the "visible" column in the main Banner table (having this table the PK on id_banner column) and create an other table containing the value of the visible banner.